# What was the most expensive arson in history? -- Was it the burning of the USS Bonhomme Richard (LHD-6)?

Tags: disasters

It was [just reported](https://fox5sandiego.com/news/local-news/fire-damaged-uss-bonhomme-richard-decommissioned-in-san-diego-ceremony/) that the USS Bonhomme Richard will be decommissioned; the repair costs would be $2.5 to 3.2 billion USD.  The replacement cost, according to Wikipedia, would be $4 billion and they intend to salvage some of the ship to offset costs.  The fire is suspected to have been an arson, but no one has been charged with the crime.

If true, this made me wonder if this was "the most expensive arson in history", and searching for said arson [finds commentary](https://www.maritimeherald.com/2020/deliberate-fire-aboard-a-us-ship-can-become-the-most-expensive-arson-in-history/) to that effect.  My question is if that was true in some notionally constant currency, such as the weight of gold?

I find myself wondering, for example, about the famous arson by [Herostratus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herostratus) of the Temple of Artemis, built with the wealth of Croesus, which when rebuilt was called one of the ancient wonders of the world.  (Like the burning of the Bonhomme Richard and the [$450+ million attack](https://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2014/mar/28/navy-says-goodbye-to-fire-damaged-submarine/) on the [USS Miami](https://www.wearethemighty.com/popular/submarine-fire-uss-miami/), that fire is believed to have been started by one person with oily rags)

Surprisingly, the [cost of wildfires](https://www.hcn.org/articles/the-10-most-expensive-wildfires-in-the-wests-history) in the U.S., arson or otherwise, seems to be vastly less.  The total insurance cost of all the rioting in 2020, though it astounded some commentators, is also considerably less.

What *was* the most expensive arson - defined as a fire started from a single place - in all of history?

Comment: The [burning of the Reichstag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reichstag_fire)

Comment: I'd go with 9/11 (destruction of the WTC mostly through fire). I am not quite sure though what qualifies as *arson* in the context of your question.

Comment: Your "just reported" link is paywalled.

Comment: Problem here is going to be costing, especially for the more distant past. For USS Bonhomme Richard, arson is "believed" but not yet confirmed. The article also mentions the USS Miami arson ($2,6 billion dollars). Seems you should include that in your question, and it may well be the answer until USS Bonhomme Richard is confirmed as arson.

Comment: I replaced the link (apparently some people see it paywalled and others don't) and mentioned the USS Miami, and acknowledged I'm taking the nature of the fire as arson as an assumption.  9/11 is a more difficult issue - ten people with hijacked planes seem qualitatively different from an attack with rags and a lighter, but I'm not sure how to express the distinction.

Comment: Please note that your definition of 'arson' as *"a fire started from a single place"* does not match any dictionary definition that I am aware of. Webster's, for example' gives *"the willful or malicious burning of property (such as a building) especially with criminal or fraudulent intent"*. Please clarify either by revising your definition or by removing the word 'arson' from your question.

Comment: The problem with establishing the "most expensive" throughout history is finding a meaningful way of comparing monetary values in events that can be hundreds or thousands of years apart.

Comment: The cost of an arson is not the cost of rebuilding, but the cost of replacing the value lost. This *might* be a rebuilding or it might be a scrapping plus construction of a new unit (less depreciation) or it might simply be the depreciated value of the thing destroyed. (If an old ship near the end of its life is destroyed, the value lost is much smaller than if it had happened new.)  This is *not* a simple question!

Comment: Is Mrs O'Leary's cow a suspect? :)

Comment: I presume you mean to exclude military activity?   Because Nagasaki and Hiroshima were both destroyed with fires started from a single place, strictly speaking.

Comment: A big problem in general is it's really hard to figure out what fires were "arson" by any definition.  (Was, for example, the burning of Moscow intentional?)   And even with that, I don't know how you compare cost across millennia?

Comment: Also, your link on "most expensive wildfires in the West" link is wildly out of date.  It's from 2016, but the [seven largest California wildfires in history are from 2017 and later](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_California_wildfires).  For instance, the damage from the 2018 fires in California is estimated at [$26.5 billion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_California_wildfires)

Answer (score 3):

Let me expand my comment to an answer.

1. First of all, I agree with Lars that it is hard, if not impossible, to compare cost of fires from different eras, especially if some of these fires happened before the modern accounting and recording of costs. Even in the cases of Hiroshima/Nagasaki destruction, which both happened in the modern era, I am unaware of any estimates of the costs.
2. It is not exactly clear what "cost" really means. The minimalistic option is to go with the replacement value of the destroyed property, but what if the property was never replaced (as in the WTC attacks case)? What about the cost of the lost human lives/health? What about the costs of fire containment and clean-up? What about the immediate costs to the (local or global) economy?
3. It is also unclear to me what "single place" in your definition of arson means. For instance, in the case of WTC attacks, was the entire WTC a *single place* or *two places* (the separate towers)?

In any case, if we restrict to post-WWII period, my estimate is that 9/11 WTC attack(s) constitute the costliest arson(s). Why was it an act of arson: The dictionary definition of arson is "the criminal act of deliberately setting fire to property" does not take into account the mechanism of arson, whether it is done using matches and gasoline (as an  accelerant) or airplanes and airplane fuel (as an accelerant). Some of the costs are documented at the Wikipedia article [Economic effects of the September 11 attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economic_effects_of_the_September_11_attck). In particular,

> The attacks themselves resulted in approximately $40 billion in insurance losses

Yes, one can count four attacks on 9/11/2001, but most insurance losses would be due to the WTC destruction. So, a crude estimate of insurance losses for each tower would be over 15 billion USD.

Furthermore, there were direct economic losses, just to NYC (from the same article) and the cost of clean-up:

> The GDP for New York City was estimated to have declined by $30.3 billion over the last three months of 2001 and all of 2002. The Federal government provided $11.2 billion in immediate assistance to the Government of New York City in September 2001, and $10.5 billion in early 2002 for economic development and infrastructure needs.

And I am not even counting the cost of the US war in Afghanistan (with costs running over a trillion of USD) which was a direct consequence of the attacks.

How does this compare to the costs of the fires to Hiroshima or Nagasaki or great fires of Rome, London, Moscow, Smirna, etc, I do not know: I do not think we have enough data for such a comparison. Furthermore, I do not think any of the latter are known to be due to an act of arson at a single place. From what I know, the Great Fire of London was caused by an accident; nobody exactly knows the causes of the Great fires of Rome and Moscow. In the case of Smirna, opinions vary, but the sources I know point to multiple arsons at various locations, rather than a single act of arson. I think, this is one thing on which different sources agree in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Destroying 2/3 of Rome, the [Great Fire of Rome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Fire_of_Rome) was probably the most expensive fire in history. The [Great Fire of London](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Fire_of_London) and the [Great Fire of Smyrna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_fire_of_Smyrna) come close, as well.

Comment: The Great Fire of Smyrna might qualify as arson but I can't see how the two do.

Comment: @LarsBosteen the definition is "a fire started from a single place", though.

Comment: @Allure Then you could say Mrs. O'Leary's cow committed arson.

Comment: @Spencer right, but it is the definition given by the OP.